# Using SonarQube groups for ldap users

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

I'm trying to achieve the following scenario in SonarQube
I already enabled ldap authentication for users
I do not want to use domain groups for managing permissions. Instead I would like to create pure "SonarQube only" group and add domain users to it.
As an admin I can do this, and UI shows that user is added (db contains this mapping as well) but as soon as this user tries to log into the SonarQube the application drops this group mapping. I can understand why it does it, but I'm looking for a way to enable this scenario to work.
This is possible with many other apps like Jira, Confluence, Nexus etc so it would sound strange if this is not possible with SonarQube at all.

sonarqube version 5.3

ldap plugin version 1.5.1

my config looks like the following

```
sonar.security.realm=LDAP
ldap.authentication=DIGEST-MD5

sonar.forceAuthentication=fasle

sonar.authenticator.createUsers=false
ldap.windows.compatibilityMode=false
sonar.security.updateUserAttributes=false

ldap.url=ldap://*****:389

ldap.bindDn=*****
ldap.bindPassword=******

ldap.user.baseDn=****
ldap.user.request=(&(objectCategory=User)(sAMAccountName={login}))
ldap.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.windows.user.realNameAttribute=cn
ldap.user.emailAttribute=mail
```

Comment: What does your LDAP config look like in `sonar.properties` ? (and please give the usual details about SonarQube/Plugin version)

Comment: I noticed this behaviour when I started, l think this requires stopping user information synchronization from LDAP server. Later I switched to use domain groups using external role mapping into roles in Nexus. It's a lot easier to native to Nexus's design.

Comment: @n_stan sure, here it is, I've updated the question

Comment: Thanks. Is SonarQube running on a Windows machine which is part of the AD domain itself ?

Comment: @n_stan
Yes, it's a windows server 2012 R2, and it's a part of domain. I use service AD account for making LPAD queries, this account can query entire AD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `ldap.windows.auth=false` in your `sonar.properties`. Since you did not configure the `ldap.group.*` properties, Group Mapping will be disabled and you can then handle groups directly in SonarQube.

Group Mapping is automatically enabled if `ldap.windows.auth=true` (default value on Windows), hence the behaviour you're observing (SonarQube group settings are overridden by the membership info in LDAP/AD).